# NopCommerce 2.5 Homepage sort order

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

NopCommerce 2.5

I want to sort the products on the home page on the display order given in Admin/Category/Edit/... but I can't find the table that the display order is held in. I have the query in Nop.Services\Catalog\ProductService.cs and I guess I need to set up a Join here but with which table???.

```
public virtual IList<Product> GetAllProductsDisplayedOnHomePage()
{
    var query = from p in _productRepository.Table
            orderby p.Name
            where p.Published &&
            !p.Deleted &&
            p.ShowOnHomePage
            select p;
    var products = query.ToList();
    return products;
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction, or even better fill in the gaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is quite late but...

No way to modify the default order. In the code above you see the "ORDER BY Name" is hardcoded. This is a big flaw of nopCommerce. There's no table or field that stores the DisplayOrder on HomePage, because there's no HomePage <-> Product relation at all, it's just a switch: it's either ON or OFF.

Comment: Btw, I've seen some people get around this using spaces in the names... But I'd rather go with a plugin if you want configuration and such ;)